# Get user full_name in .values() Django ORM

Tags: mysql, django, orm, modal-dialog

How to get `user__get_full_name` while selecting `.values()` on any modal?

```
Pageview.objects.values('visitor__user__username').annotate(url_count=Count('url')).annotate(url_count_unique=Count('url', distinct=True))
```

I want to

1. Rename `visitor__user__username` to some alias for example `user`
2. Get user's `full_name` instead of username
3. Optimize the query if possible.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Get full name is a method on the user model and does not map directly to a db row attribute. You wont be able to get it with .values().